# React Router Dom v6, Routes keep adding

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I set up React Router Dom and changed through routes, Routes keep adding Infront.

Example:- If I'm on the `http://localhost:3001/login` page and I click to Register Link `register` route is added in front like this ==> `http://localhost:3001/login/register`

Can anyone show me what have I done wrong?

**Codes**

**App.js**

```
import "./App.scss";
import { Routes, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register/Register";

function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Router } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            Home
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="login">Login</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="register">Register</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**Register.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Router } from "react-router-dom";

function Register() {
    return (
        <div>
            Register
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="login">Login</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Register;
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Router } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
    return (
        <div>
            Login
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="register">Register</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: I believe (could be wrong), that changing the Link `to` parameter to contain `/` (slash) at the beggining, should solve your problem. Final elem should look like this: `<Link to="/register">Register</Link>` -- could be wrong tho, I cannot test it rn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, that changing the Link `to` parameter to contain `/` (slash) at the beggining, should solve your problem. Final elem should look like this: `<Link to="/register">Register</Link>`

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

`react-router-dom@6` uses both absolute and relative path routing/navigation. The difference between absolute and relative routing/navigation is a leading `"/"` character in paths/targets.

For example, the `Login` component is rendered on `path="/login"` and renders a link `<Link to="register">Register</Link>` to `"register"`. This means that `Login` will link to a `"register"` path ***relative*** to the current `"/login"` path, resulting in navigating to `"/login/register"`.

The same issue occurs when rendering `Register` on `path="/register"` and rendering `<Link to="login">Login</Link>`.

## Solution

### Use absolute paths:

Example:

```
function Register() {
  return (
    <div>
      Register
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
function Login() {
  return (
    <div>
      Login
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Use relative paths and navigate to a sibling route (*i.e. a sibling route rendered by the same parent `Routes` component*).

Example:

```
function Register() {
  return (
    <div>
      Register
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="../login">Login</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
function Login() {
  return (
    <div>
      Login
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="../register">Register</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```